# Возвращать JSON вместо XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Приветствую! 
Решил написать простой WEB API на С#. Создал тестовую модель данных и контроллер :

```
public class FlugController : ApiController
{
    Flug[] Flugen = new Flug[] 
    {
        new Flug { IdFlug=1, MarcFlug = "Boeng", JareFlug = "2010" },
        new Flug { IdFlug=2, MarcFlug = "AirLine", JareFlug = "2010" },
        new Flug { IdFlug=3, MarcFlug = "Aero", JareFlug = "2010" },

    };

    public IEnumerable<Flug> GetAllFlug()
    {
        return  Flugen;
    }
    public IHttpActionResult GetFlug(int id)
    {
        Flug FlugByID = Flugen.FirstOrDefault((c)=>c.IdFlug == id);
        if (FlugByID != null)
            return  Ok(FlugByID);
        else return NotFound();
    }
}
```

Все работает нормально за исключением, того что данные возвращаются в xml формате :

```
<ArrayOfFlug xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebApplication2.Models">
<Flug>
<IdFlug>1</IdFlug>
<JareFlug>2010</JareFlug>
<MarcFlug>Boeng</MarcFlug>
</Flug>
<Flug>
<IdFlug>2</IdFlug>
<JareFlug>2010</JareFlug>
<MarcFlug>AirLine</MarcFlug>
</Flug>
<Flug>
<IdFlug>3</IdFlug>
<JareFlug>2010</JareFlug>
<MarcFlug>Aero</MarcFlug>
</Flug>
</ArrayOfFlug>
```

В принципе нормально,но xml слишком многословен. Вопрос - как переделать API что бы возвращал данные в JSON ?

Comment: Так вы когда запрос отправляете в WEB.API контроллер, какой тип контента указываете? Просите присылапть json, будет вам json

Comment: @tym32167 запрс - `http://localhost:8970/api/flug` а как ему тип указать?

Comment: Это не запрос, это просто Url. Если вы говорим о GET запросе, то по данному Url можно отправлять запрос вместе с заголовками. Есть такой заголовок - ```Accept```, вы можете его отправить вместе с вашим GET запросом и указать его значение как ```application/json```. Когда WEB.API будет считывать ваш запрос, оно считает в том числе и заголовок, что вы отправили. И если вы ничего сами явно не указывали, то WEB.API будет выдавать ответ в соответствии с тем заголовком, что вы прислали, то есть в виде json.

Comment: Если же вы открываете ваш URL просто в браузере, то ваш браузер скорее всего отправляет этот заголовок со значением ```text\html```. Чтобы в браузере увидеть ответ вашего контроллера в json, для asp.net web api надо в конфиге прописать, что мол даже если тип контента запрашивается ```text\html```, то все равно возвращать json. Как это сделать написано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome) и [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation)

Comment: @tym32167, почему не в виде ответа?

Comment: @Андрей окей, сделал ответом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такой заголовок - `Accept`, вы можете его отправить вместе с вашим `GET` запросом и указать его значение как `application/json`. Когда `WEB.API` будет считывать ваш запрос, оно считает в том числе и заголовок, что вы отправили. И если вы ничего сами явно не указывали, то `WEB.API` будет выдавать ответ в соответствии с тем заголовком, что вы прислали, то есть в виде `json`.

Если же вы открываете ваш URL просто в браузере, то ваш браузер скорее всего отправляет этот заголовок со значением `text\html`. Чтобы в браузере увидеть ответ вашего контроллера в `json`, для `asp.net web api` надо в конфиге прописать, что мол даже если тип контента запрашивается `text\html`, то все равно возвращать `json`. Как это сделать написано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome) и [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation). В частности, вы можете добавить в конфигурацию вашего приложения следующее

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes
    .Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html") );
```